# Passing array from Django view to HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, django

I'm sending an array from a django view to an html (in which there is a JS script) but the array seems to be a string. In fact if I try to console.log(array[0]) or console.log(array[1]) it returns in the first case [ and in the second case '

The code is:

Django view

```
def results(request):
   h = request.POST['h']   
   name = request.POST['name']

   array = [h, name]
return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'h':h, 'array':array})
```

index.html

```
<script>
   var h = "{{ h }}"   //this is 3 
   var array = "{{ array|safe }}"  //this is ['3', 'John']
   console.log(h)
   console.log(array[0])
   console.log(array[1])
```

The console is:

```
3 

[

'
```

I wish it was:

```
3

3

John
```

Do you have any idea how can I access the n value of the array? Thanks

Comment: Could you try remove quotes.So, can you use {{ array|safe }} instead of "{{ array|safe }}"?

Comment: No! It is mandatory for calling variable from django view, without quotes it doesn't even compile anymore

Comment: I think it is not, could you try it?

Comment: I tried, the code editor was giving me an error, but at the end I ran the code and it worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{ array|safe }}` instead of `"{{ array|safe }}"` withouth any extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the package [django-jsonify](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonify/)

```
pip install django-jsonify
```

Then add **jsonify** to django INSTALLED_APPS

In your template

```
{% load jsonify %}

var array = {{ array|jsonify }}
```

Hope this helps you, if any thing please let me know.

Comment: If I use this approach I got two errors: 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at the line of var array)

Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined (at the line I will use h)

Comment: try removing the double quotes var array = {{ array|jsonify }}